# URL for button "create new list item"

Tags: sharepoint-online

Using office 365 SharePoint on cloud.

I need a url to buttons create new list item. Is there any way to get it? I need to setup a hyperlink where user presses it and form instantly opens up. On SP2013 I was able to achieve that with just right clicking on new item and getting the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<<root url of your list>>/NewForm.aspx` will take you the full page input form for the list.  This will work regardless of whether you are using Modern or Classic.  For example: `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/demosite/Lists/mycustomlist/NewForm.aspx`.

The old `Source` url parameter works as well, just as it has in most prior versions of SharePoint.  This parameter tells SharePoint what page to redirect the user to after they save the new Item.  If this parameter is omitted, SharePoint automatically takes the user to the default view of the List.  For example, if your link/button takes the user to `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/demosite/Lists/mycustomlist/NewForm.aspx?Source=https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/demosite/sitepages/thankyouforsubmitting.aspx` then you can have a custom thank you page displayed after the user clicks `save`.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I remembered about newform.aspx after I posted this